Scipy minimize with conditioning
I have a function of 3 variables that I want to optimize. Unfortunately, the variables have different orders of magnitude, meaning that the problem is very ill-conditioned. I'm handling this by multiplying the optimization variable by a conditioning matrix. (In the example below, my conditioning matrix is diagonal, so I've implemented it as a vector. There may be applications for non-diagonal conditioning matrices.)
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def penalty(x):
    # do stuff
    return # result

conditioner = np.array([1000, 1, 0.1])
x0 = np.array([0.003, 1.415, 9.265]) * conditioner 
optim_result = minimize(penalty, x0)
bestfit = optim_result.x / conditioner 

Is there a way to do this that doesn't require the manual application of conditioner or require me to keep track of which data are conditioned (e.g., bestfit) and which are not (e.g., optim_result)?
I suppose I could put some of the arithmetic inside the penalty function, like this:
def penalty(x):
    x_cond = x * conditioner
    # do stuff
    return # result

but it only solves half of the problem.

This makes no sense. Do you realise that for any function that has a global minimum, changing x0 would have no effect on the result, then why would you rescale bestfit after and move it away from your actual minimum? Do you actually understand what you are doing here?

Maybe provide an actual [mre]...

Yes, my pseudo-example is missing something, but someone gave a detailed and correct answer anyway, and your questioning of my intelligence isn't motivating me to go and fix my question.

Code
A simple way of doing that would be to write a wrapper for minimize() which handles the task of converting into and out of this new coordinate system.
At minimum, this wrapper needs to do three things:

Change the initial x0 point into the coordinate system.
Change the x value out of the coordinate system each time your function is called.
Change the x value out of the coordinate system when the optimization is done.

That can be done like this:
import scipy


def minimize_with_parameter_scaling(f, x0, typical_x_value=None, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapped_f(x, *args, **kwargs):
        return f(x * typical_x_value, *args, **kwargs)
    x0 = np.asarray(x0)
    if typical_x_value is None:
        typical_x_value = np.ones_like(x0)
    typical_x_value = np.asarray(typical_x_value)
    assert (typical_x_value != 0).all(), "parameter scale cannot be zero"
    x0_scaled = x0 / typical_x_value
    result = scipy.optimize.minimize(wrapped_f, x0_scaled, *args, **kwargs)
    result.x = result.x * typical_x_value
    return result

Warning: typical_x_value has the inverse meaning of conditioner in your example, and instead represents how large a typical x value is.
This function could be called like this:
x0 = [0, 0, 0]
scale = [1, 0.01, 1]
result = minimize_with_parameter_scaling(wacky_rosenbrock, x0, scale)

Let's also try this out on an example problem, to see if the hypothesis that conditioning will help is correct.
An example problem
The example problem I chose is the rosenbrock function, which is a function designed to test nonlinear optimizers. It is a nonlinear function with a global minimum, which has derivatives which are misleading to optimizers, which is why it is a hard problem.
To provide a problem with inappropriate scale, I made one of the coordinates have a different scale than the others.
def wacky_rosenbrock(x):
    # Code copied from scipy.optimize.rosen
    x = np.asarray(x)
    x[1] *= 100  # Second coordinate is multiplied by 100
    r = np.sum(100.0 * (x[1:] - x[:-1]**2.0)**2.0 + (1 - x[:-1])**2.0,
                  axis=0)
    return r

Results
I then attempted to solve wacky_rosenbrock() in three dimensions. I tried solving it without scaling, and with a scaling of [1, 0.01, 1]. The nfev are the number of function calls it took to get the solution. The error is the percentage error of the solution the optimizer found versus the actual best solution. The last column is how many times more function calls it takes without scaling. I also tried a variety of SciPy's solvers.



method
error (no scaling)
nfev (no scaling)
error (scaling)
nfev (scaling)
improvement in function call count




nelder-mead
0.001%
305
0.003%
289
1.05536


powell
0.0%
862
0.0%
886
0.972912


cg
0.239%
1772
0.0%
248
7.14516


bfgs
0.035%
340
0.001%
148
2.2973


l-bfgs-b
0.023%
268
0.0%
140
1.91429


tnc
37.086%
404
0.015%
400
1.01


cobyla
98.729%
39
11.214%
4087
0.00954245


cobyqa
0.008%
1406
0.0%
157
8.95541


slsqp
0.042%
128
0.049%
112
1.14286


trust-constr
0.038%
264
0.001%
232
1.13793



Discussion
In these results, I want to point out the following things:

For many solvers, such as BFGS, L-BFGS-B, and COBYQA, re-scaling allows the problem to be solved much more quickly.
For some solvers, it makes no difference. In particular, the derivative free solvers Nelder-Mead and Powell don't care.
The choice of solver matters more than the use of scaling. For example, you could optimize L-BFGS-B from 280 to 140 calls by using scaling. But you could switch to SLSQP instead, which is both less work than the scaling I describe in this answer, and only uses 128 calls.

